# Generate Java classes from XMLRPC API

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-rpc

I'm trying to generate Java classes with JAXB, and I need to extract .xsd schema from the call of a XMLRPC API. Is there a method for doing this? An example of a XMLRPC call is

```
<methodCall>
  <methodName>acquire_token</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>username</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>password</string>
      </value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <value>
        <string>0978900008508</string>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```